# Default to SeaBIOS after installing Gallium and removing ChromeOS

Tags: boot, chrome-book

I followed John Lewis' [instructions](https://johnlewis.ie/neutering-the-developer-mode-screen-on-your-chromebook/), then installed [Gallium OS on an Acer C720](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Installing/Peppy). But I didn't realize I'd have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> every time I boot.

**Can I make SeaBIOS/Gallium the default boot option** and can I make those changes from Gallium, or do I need to boot the machine in ChromeOS somehow? If so, can I create a boot drive to do that, or do I need to restore ChromeOS? I have the ChromeOS restore on an SD card and the Gallium installer on a USB drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge you need Chrome OS and crosh to make the changes.

I used [MrChromebox Firmware Utility Script](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript) to make these changes, now it boots to SeaBIOS/Gallium in 2s on my N22 and I removed the bitmaps, too:

> 4. **Set Boot Options (GBB Flags)**
>
>    This script function allows one to change the timeout for the Developer Mode boot screen (2s or 30s) and the default boot target (ChromeOS or Legacy Boot Mode). Setting the boot target to Legacy Boot removes the requirement of pressing [CTRL+L] at boot; instead, you must press [CTRL+D] to boot ChromeOS. This function is just a wrapper around the gbb_utility application built into ChromeOS that will read the GBB region from the stock firmware, set the GBB flags based on user input, and write it back to flash. …
>
> …
>
> 6. **Remove ChromeOS Bitmaps**
>
>    This function removes the ChromeOS bitmap (image) files used to display the Developer Mode and Recovery boot screens, leaving you with a simple black screen with white terminal text …

Edit: I had to remove the write protect screw to make the changes.

Comment: Accepted answer for needing to go into Chrome OS and crosh and also for using a simpler method than I did all those months ago. Thanks! :)